# iOS OpenGL ES compatible with Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, cross-platform, ios, compatibility

In theory, can I write a game for iOS in openGL ES and expect to easily port it to Android? How about from Android to iOS?

Comment: Porting is easier than two different APIs, but OpenGL itself doesn't guarantee same result for different hardware. Mostly similar but anyway, not guaranteed. So you still need to test all the rendering code output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I believe that if you write a game in C/C++ for iOS, to port it to Android wouldn't be too much of a hassle. However, if you write the game in Objective-C, then it could be quite a hassle indeed.

Comment: this really doesn't address the question at hand, and should NOT be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

There are differences in Android and iOS game development that you need to take into account:

In android you need to support **multiple graphics chips**:

- Different texture compression support
- Major differences in performance

Different **OpenGL ES implementations**:

- Buggy gluUnproject implementation in Android (there are [custom implementations](http://markmail.org/message/67fs76j3om7nusd2), for example )
- Lack of glGet* functions in Android (however you can use [MatrixTrackingGL](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixTrackingGL.html))